# Как сверстать картинки в шахматном порядке?

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что тут лучше использовать flex или position: absolute? По клику на картинках должны открываться ссылки

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flex через margin можно:

```css
.socials {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

.social {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: purple;
}

.social:nth-child(even) {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="socials">
  <div class="social"></div>
  <div class="social"></div>
  <div class="social"></div>
  <div class="social"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Можно без margin же, column end

Comment: @MonkeyMutant Если задать определенную высоту блоку с flex, то да. Но так понятнее)

Comment: Согласен, но там всё равно есть высота

Comment: @MonkeyMutant, `grid-column-end: auto;`? почему тогда не `align-items: flex-end;` если тут флексы?